# Evans PDE problem 9,Chapter 6

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an bounded domain with smooth boundary. Assume $u$ is a smooth solution of 
$$
Lu=-\sum_{i,j=1}^na^{i,j}u_{x_ix_j}=f \  \text{in} \ U, \ \ 
u=0 \ \text{on}  \ \partial U,
$$ where $f$ is bounded. Fix $x^0 \in \partial U$. A $barrier$ at $x^0$ is a $C^2$ function $w$ such that
$$
Lw\ge 1, \ \ w(x^0)=0, \ \ w|_{\partial U}\ge 0.
$$
Show that if $w$ is a barrier at $x^0$, there exists a constant $C$ such that 
$$
|Du(x^0)|\le C|\frac{\partial w}{\partial \nu}(x^0)|. 
$$
Note that we assume $a^{i,j}$ are smooth and satisfy uniform ellipcity.

Actually, someone asked the problem on this website two years ago, but didn't get a clear answer.This is my homework and I would appreciate it if someone could help me. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It has been asked here, but didn't have an answer [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258271/elliptic-equation-and-barrier-estimate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had this problem as homework too,and I found a solution
[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!