# Evans 2ed Chapter 6 Problem 9

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In Partial Differential Equations 2ed of Lawrence C.Evans, the Chapter 6 Problem 9, I have some problems.

In ball-pen (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/237711/ball-pen), Evans PDE problem 9,Chapter 6, URL (version: 2015-05-04): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1265988 There is a solution about it. By this I know why $ \displaystyle | \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}(x^{0})| \le C |\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \nu} (x^{0})|$, but I don't know how to get $\displaystyle | Du(x^{0})| \le C |\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \nu} (x^{0})|$, unless $ \nu \parallel Du $, however the $ \nu$ represent the outer unit normal, see 
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$, there is no tangential part to the derivative.

Comment: I understand it, and thanks for your help!