# Normal derivative when $x_0\in \partial\Omega$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

When I read the [Normal derivative of Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative#Normal_derivative) and this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261915/evans-pde-problem-9-chapter-6/1265988#1265988), I am confuse with them.

Assume $\Omega$ is bounded open subset of $R^n$ and $\partial\Omega$ is smooth, and some smooth function $f$ reach its max in $x_0\in\partial\Omega$.

Then why $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overrightarrow n}(x_0)\le 0$ ? $n$ is out normal.

If the define of direct derivative is
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}(x_0)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+t\overrightarrow n)-f(x_0)}{t}
$$

$x_0+t\overrightarrow n$ is not in $\Omega$, so, $f(x_0+t\overrightarrow n)$ is meaningless. So, I don't know how to define the direct derivative along the out normal when $x_0\in \partial\Omega$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's even worse: since $\Omega$ is open, $\partial \Omega \cap \Omega = \emptyset$, so it's not even clear if $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$ itself exists. Take for example $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ on the open interval $(0,1)$.

So, in order to define the directional derivative of $f$ at $\partial \Omega$, $f$ needs to be defined (and continuously differentiable) on an open set $U$ containing $\Omega$, i.e. $\Omega \subset U$.

However, if $f$ is **bounded** (on $\Omega$), you can say a lot more -- in particular, you can extend $f$ to an open subset containing $\Omega$, which is exactly what you need; I believe this is an application of the Whitney extension theorem, see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375530).

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ extends continuously to the boundary, you could just restrict $t$ to negative real numbers in your definition, and everything should be fine.